# Bounded type parameter vs plain base class

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

At compile time, javac [erases](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html) the generic bounded type and replaces it with the upper bound.

For example, the compiler will convert

```
<T extends Base> void foo(T p) {}
```

to

```
void foo(Base p) {}
```

In this specific case, I think the generics definitely is preferred over the other option. But I would like to know the specific advantages.

Comment: It is not equivalent. Only **after** compilation. But **during** compilation the compiler can ensure type safety with the actual `T`, not just `Base`. So just because generics are erased during runtime, does not mean they are useless. The compiler can ensure full generic type safety. So there is not much point in keeping the generic alive after the system has been verified to be correct and safe already (although this is not fully true).

Comment: @Zabuzard Great explanation! So the thing is, I should look at it at a broader scope, because the benefit really lives in what happens before compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain the need of a *Bounded Type* properly through an example.

Let's say you are writing a library or framework that are going to used by other. Let's say in somewhere(in some class method) you need to perform some **neumerical** *addition, subtraction, multiplication* etc. So, what type of data do you need for that? Of course a *Neumeric* type. So, what you've done is created a class **Number**. But, there are various type of numbers like *Floating point*, *Integer* etc. So, you've created **Integer**, **Float** subclass etc. Now, you've also created a class **NumberUtil** which gives some features to user like finding average, finding frequency of numbers etc. And of course, in a single word: **NumberUtil** is awesome, everyone wants to use it. Now, let's talk about the average method in your **NumberUtil** class(let's write some code):

```
class NumberUtil<T extends Number> {
  T[] nums;
  public NumberUtil(T[] nums) {
    this.nums = nums;
  }
  public Double average() {
    Double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
      sum = sum + nums[i].doubleValue(); // note, you've ensured T must be a number
      // so, T must able to convert it's value to double value
    }
    return sum / nums.length;
  }
}
```

Now, let's assume, some other people are using your library, specifically **NumberUtil**(cause, it's awesome), but they are using it with their own type called **SomeNumberType**. But it's possible that, this **SomeNumberType** doesn't subclass **Number** (or, it doesn't implement the **Number** interface, if you've declared **Number** as an interface). So, you can't guarantee that **SomeNumberType** will provide a *doubleValue()* method. But, by writing **T extends Number**, you've made sure in the **compile time** that **SomeNumberType** must be a **subclass of Number** and everything will work fine(at least, it would have the peropeties of Number class, and that means, it'll also have a *doubleValue()* method).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this link here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html#:%7E:text=Generic%20methods%20are%20methods%20that,well%20as%20generic%20class%20constructors.).

But in short, two things to note:

> Generic methods are methods that introduce their own type parameters. This is similar to declaring a generic type, but the type parameter's scope is limited to the method where it is declared. Static and non-static generic methods are allowed, as well as generic class constructors.

—https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

> Type inference is a Java compiler's ability to look at each method invocation and corresponding declaration to determine the type argument (or arguments) that make the invocation applicable. The inference algorithm determines the types of the arguments and, if available, the type that the result is being assigned, or returned. Finally, the inference algorithm tries to find the most specific type that works with all of the arguments.

—https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: I am sorry sir. I am new and learning on how to post answers on the platform. And thank you for rearranging the answer much appreciated sir.

Comment: Great =) Thanks for accepting feedback